# bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

I just started programming with Ruby on Rails and I really like it. I have a small page with a form (using gem simple_form) and I also integrated twitter bootstrap.

This part is working fine. But now I want to use the bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails editor (https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails).

This is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for (@article) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :title, label: 'Titel' %>
<%= f.input :body, label: 'Content' %>
<%= f.input :tag_list, label: 'Tags' %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I setup the dependencies css and javascript.

I want to use the wysiwyg editor for the content field but I don't know how.. Can anyone give me an exampe for the content field?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your form, for the content field do

```
 <%= f.input :content, label: 'Content' , input_html: { class: 'wysihtml5' } %>
```

Then in your application.js add

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.wysihtml5').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(elem).wysihtml5();
  });
})
```

Comment: The class name should be same in input and in javascript code. :)

Comment: Trying to answer on mobile!